# MysqlConnector/C or MysqlConnector/C++ to use?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, c, visual-studio

I use visual studio 2012. I have console application. I should connect to mysql server, i use mysql Connector/C++, but when i read from table, for example if i should get 'word' i get instead four unknown symbols, 'word' and after that many unknown symbols (also there are words) and ends with fatal error. What is problem? should i use connector C?

This is my code`

```
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
stmt = con->createStatement();
stmt->execute("USE mail_members");
sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id FROM messages");
int k = 0;
res->next();
std::cout << res->getString("id").asStdString();
delete con;
delete stmt;
```

Are anyone use Mysql connector.c++ ?

P.S. This is my messages table`

```
Field    Type    NULL     Key     Default  |  Extra
id       int(11) Yes              NULL
message  text    YES              NULL
```

I use MysqlConnector/C# in other application and it works correctly, may be this don't work because my application is consiole (with stdafx files)?

Comment: Please edit your post with the results from the command "DESCRIBE messages;"

Comment: MySQL Connector/C++ is built for VS 2008 and uses `std::` classes from MS VC 2008 runtime, which are incompatible with `std::` classes from MS VC 2010/2012/etc. runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code throwing any exceptions?

I put the field name into an `std::string` and then pass to the resultset methods:

```
const std::string   name = fri.get_field_name();
unsigned int        result_value = m_resultset.getUInt(name);
```

In my tables, the record ID field is an integer not a string.

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Title | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Title    | varchar(64)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Is your ID field a string?

Comment: Yes it throws but i don't know what exception (i don't catch).

Comment: Don't use `res->getString`.  Use `res->getInt()` to get your ID field.  According to your table, the field is an integer, not a string.

Comment: Thanks, for int it works. I find why it outputs unknown symbols, if i write res->getString(sql::SQLString("name")), it don't output symbols, but i can't get varchar fields, 'name' is varchar(32), and when i run that command i get nothing(the same for char), what can be reason?

Comment: Also in name = fri.get_field_name() what is fri?

Comment: In my example, `fri` is an instance of a `Field_Integer` interface class having a method that returns the name of the field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602199/mysql-c-connector-getstring-returns-wchar-collation This is answer for my question, it finally works :))) Thank you too Thomas!!!